# How do I resolve An error has occurred! undefined exports: jquery_core iin R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

i'm new to R shiny and I'm trying to build my first app.
I run the code that is provided when creating the shiny app on R studio and I have this result :

> **An error has occurred! undefined exports: jquery_core**

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I'm using windows and R4.1.1

Thx for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I actually found a solution. Turns out the problem was caused by a bug in Onedrive. A library called `jquerylib` wasn’t sync properly and that was affected the process of R rendering the shiny app.